# Read input text on a button submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc

**HTML**

```
<div class="fc-option-more-input">
     <input type="number" id="itemCount">
     <button type="submit" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("AddToCart", "Controller", new { id = Model[i].ItemID, itemCount = ??? })'" class="button button-add-custom-qty" disabled="disabled">
         <span>Add</span>
     </button>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult AddToCart(int id, int itemCount)
    {
        var ItemToAdd = db.Items
            .Single(item => item.ItemID == id);
        var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);
        ItemVM model = new ItemVM();
        model.ID = ItemToAdd.ItemID;
        model.ItemName = ItemToAdd.ItemName;
        model.ItemPrice = ItemToAdd.ItemPrice;
        model.ImageURL = ItemToAdd.ImageUrl;
        model.ItemPrice = ItemToAdd.ItemPrice * itemCount;
        cart.AddToCart(model, itemCount);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

When button is clicked, I need to somehow read the text input (number) of input element and post it to controller. How can this be achieved ?

Comment: You can either wrap it in a form, or use JavaScript and Ajax. In general, in a web page, those are the two ways you can send data to the server. Those are always your options

Comment: I've tried both the form and using javaScript/ajax but to no avail. Please see the answer given below in relevance to your comment. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or use Form with Razor code, it like this:

```
<div class="fc-option-more-input">
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "Controller", new { id = 0 }, FormMethod.Post))
{
  <input type="number" id="itemCount" name="itemCount"/>
  <button type="submit"><span>Add</span></button>
}
</div>
```

Comment: Your suggestion is successfully posting data to `AddToCart` action but not giving normal control to it as last line of code in `AddToCart` is `return RedirectToAction("Index");` and it is not being executed

Comment: So, let use html form to send request

Comment: Can you please demonstrate it?

Comment: Edited in my answer

Comment: Is @Model[i].itemID posted?

Comment: `The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult AddToCart(Int32, Int32)' in 'OnlineStore.Controllers.ShoppingCartController'.`

Comment: `routes.MapRoute(
                name: "AddToCart",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/",
                defaults: new { controller = "ShoppingCart", action = "AddToCart" }
            );`

Comment: I've also added 1 more route to same action as: 

`routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Price",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{itemCount}",
                defaults: new { controller = "ShoppingCart", action = "AddToCart", id = "", itemCount = "" }
                );`

Comment: I added id parameter in my answer, hope it help

Comment: `The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'itemCount' `

Comment: Type something to your input tag, don't let it null

Comment: add button is disabled by default. It's active only when user types a number in it.

Comment: I tested on my local and it working completely if input tag has some number. Otherwise, it give me "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'itemCount'" as you say.

Comment: Please remove the ajax code since it didn't solve it. HTML code is the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why are you not using model to submit your forms with controller side

```
@model AddToCart
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))
{
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ItemCount )
  <button type="submit"><span>Add</span></button>
}
</div>
```

### Controller

```
public ActionResult AddToCart(AddToCart model)
    {
        var ItemToAdd = db.Items
            .Single(item => item.ItemID == model.Id);
 cart.AddToCart(model, model.ItemCount);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

### Model  - AddToCart.cs

```
public int Id {get;set;}
public int ItemCount {get;set;}
```

Model is one type of class and if your model is another folder then you can give reference by @using just below @model in cshtml file 
where Id is your item id and add in your page with hidden so it will be available in model in controller side

Answer (score 0):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "ShoppingCart", new { id = Model[i].ItemID}, FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="fc-option-more-input">
     <input type="number" id="itemCount" name="itemCount">
     <button type="submit" class="button button-add-custom-qty" disabled="disabled">
         <span>Add</span>
     </button>
}
</div>
```

This solved it for me.